# Error al conectar a mi usuario creado de PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Soy nuevo usando PostgreSQL, por lo que puede que sea un problema tonto. Esto es así:
Me cree un usuario desde postgres:

`postgres=# CREATE USER "Brianlider" WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'xxxxxx'`

Luego verifico que este dentro de la lista de roles y efectivamente está:

```
 Nombre de rol |                         Atributos                          | Miembro de
---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 Brianlider    | Superusuario                                               | {}
 postgres      | Superusuario, Crear rol, Crear BD, Replicaci¾n, Ignora RLS | {}
```

Entonces me deslogeo con \q, y quiero entrar a mi usuario para que aparezca:

> Brianlider=# (o supongo que así debería aparecer xD)

Pero me tira:

```
>PS C:\Users\Dell> psql -U Brianlider
Contraseña para usuario Brianlider: xxxxxx
psql: error: no se pudo conectar al servidor: FATAL:  no existe la base de datos «Brianlider»
```

No entiendo porque dice que es una base de datos, cuando creo que lo estoy haciendo correctamente. Estuve buscando por todos lados y no encuentro una solución específica a este problema.

Espero que toda esta información que proporcione sea suficiente. Si necesitan más, lo respondo al instante.

Saludos y gracias por la ayuda !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma predeterminada, postgres intenta conectarse a una base de datos con el mismo nombre que el usuario. Para evitar este comportamiento por defecto, sólo tiene que especificar el usuario y la base de datos.

psql -U Username DatabaseName

Espero te sirva. Saludos!